# What's “hamburger button” means?

Tags: word-meaning, terminology

I read a sentence

> Instead of a menu bar and a toolbar, we will use a drawer from which the user can pick the actions. The drawer can swiped in from the side, but we also offer a hamburger button in the header.

What does a ‘hamburger button’ mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In English, the hamburger menu, or the hamburger icon, is the button in websites and apps that typically opens up into a side menu or navigation drawer.

The button shows three horizontal lines or bars stacked vertically suggesting items in a list, and is named as it is because it slightly resembles the three elements of a traditional hamburger in a bun.

It was created by interaction designer Norm Cox for the Xerox Star personal workstation in 1981 as an easy way to communicate to users that the button contained a list of items.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First time I've ever encountered the term.

Comment: @ColinFine - I saw them and learned how to use them long before I learned what they were called, or even that they had a name. But how many ordinary users know the names of common user interface items? I recently had a colleague say "What?" when I said they could select something using a 'radio button'.

Comment: the picture is well to show me what's `hamburger button` means.

Comment: @ColinFine the symbol is present on the top left hand side in the black toolbar.  By visiting Meta I get to learn a lot of computer design terms.